# Can we merge as a single column

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, declare, nsregularexpression

```
select
    case 
        when 'A-3258' like 'A-3258' 
            then '3258' 
            else 'Unwanted' 
    end as R1,
    trim(leading '-' from (trim(leading 'B' from ('B-3258')))) as R2 
from 
    dual;
```

Can we make results in single column.

```
R1    R2
==    ==
3258  3258
```

Expecting

```
R1
==
3258
3258
```

Comment: You can do something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/uRYH-YvO